# How do I create thread pools in Play 2.5.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, threadpool, playframework-2.5

I am currently on Play 2.4.2 and have successfully created thread pools using the following below:

```
package threads

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.Play.current

object Contexts {
  implicit val db: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.db-context")
  implicit val pdf: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.pdf-context")
  implicit val email: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.email-context")
}
```

and then in the code with...

```
Future{....}(threads.Contexts.db)
```

We are ready to upgrade to Play 2.5 and having trouble understanding the documentation.  The documentation for 2.4.2 uses Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup, which we use without issue.  The documentation for 2.5.x uses app.actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup.  As far as I know, I have to inject the app into a Class, not an Object.  Yet the documentation clearly uses an Object for the example!

Has anyone successfully created thread pools in Play 2.5.x that can help out?  Is it as simple as changing Contexts to a class, then injecting it wherever I would like to use this threading?  Seems odd since to use the default ExecutionContext I just have to make an implicit import.

Also, we are using Play scala.

Comment: implicit lookups happen by type, you don't want multiple objects with the same type in implicit scope, so I wouldn't do the implicit annotation here. Take into scope as needed via `implicit val ec = Contexts.db` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply change your `Contexts` to a class, then you will have to deal with how to get an instance of that class.

In my opinion, if you have a number of thread pools that you want to make use of, named bindings are the way to go. In the below example, I will show you how you could accomplish this with guice.

Note that guice injects depedencies [at runtime](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection), but it is also possible to inject dependencies at [compile time](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection).

I'm going to show it with the db context as an example. First, this is how you will be using it:

```
class MyService @Inject() (@Named("db") dbCtx: ExecutionContext) {
  // make db access here
}
```

And here's how you could define the binding:

```
bind[ExecutionContext].qualifiedWith("db").toProvider[DbExecutionContextProvider]
```

And somewhere define the provider:

```
class DbExecutionContextProvider @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends Provider[ExecutionContext] {
  override def get(): ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.db-context")
}
```

You will have to do this for each of your contexts. I understand this may be a little cumbersome and there may actually be more elegant ways to define the bindings in guice.

Note that I have not tried this out. One issue you might stumble upon could be that you'll end up with conflicts, because play already defines a binding for the `ExecutionContext` in their `BuiltinModule`. You may need to override the binding to work around that.